# PHP - making this code shorter

Tags: php, loops, if-statement

I have this PHP code (get_option is Wordpress function).

```
    <?php $hahaha = get_option('hahaha'); 
    if(empty($hahaha)) { 
       echo 'false'; 
    } 
    else { 
       echo 'true'; 
    }
?>
```

The code looks lame to me, is there a way of making it shorter like (my imagination ;)):

```
<?php $hahaha = get_option('hahaha');
if($hahaha): 'true' // 'false'
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$hahaha = get_option('hahaha'); 
echo $hahaha ? 'true' : 'false';
```

There's no need for `empty`, since the variable is definitely set. A pure boolean comparison works just fine.

If you don't need the variable later on for something else, you can skip it as well:

```
echo get_option('hahaha') ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ternary operator, but I'm not sure it does much for readability:

```
echo (empty($hahaha) ? 'false' : 'true');
```

Comment: I don't see why the conditional operator is so maligned. What you posted is just as readable to me as an if statement. It's only detrimental to readability when it's abused with much more complex expressions.

Answer (score 2):

```
$hahaha = get_option('hahaha');
echo empty($hahaha) ? 'true' : 'false';
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary for more details about the ternary operator.

Comment: That's flip-flopped from what he's got in the question, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo empty($hahaha)?'false':'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo empty($hahaha = get_option('hahaha')) ? 'false' : 'true';
```

Comment: That's invalid code. `empty` is a language construct and cannot be used with expressions. Besides, `empty` is just the same as `== false` but without throwing a notice for non-set variables, so it is useless here. `echo !get_option('hahaha') ? ...` would have done the same (without failing of course).

Answer (score 0):

This will display 0 or 1

`$options = get_options(...);`

`echo empty($options);`
OR
`echo !empty($options);`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php $hahaha = get_option('hahaha');
echo (isset($hahaha)) ? 'true': 'false';
```

Comment: Unless `get_option` returns `null`, this will always evaluate to true. `empty($a)` is like `$a == false`, and `isset($a)` is like `$a !== null`. Except that both `empty` and `isset` doesn't spit out notices. See the [Type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to know what `== false`.